# Passing list of arguments of varying length

Tags: python

this is probably a dumb question so I'll keep it as simple as possible.

I am have a list of varying number of lists (x) and I'm trying to pass each list to the function itertools.product(), but I can't get it to work.

```
x = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
itertools.product(x[0], x[1], x[2]...)
```

I have tried:

```
itertools.product(x[n] for n in range(len(x)))
itertools.product(n for n in x)
```

My function would hopefully behave:

```
output = []
for product in itertools.product(x[n] for n in range(len(x))):
    output.append(product)
output """--> [(a, d), (a, e)...]"""
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
x = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
itertools.product(*x)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Same as always.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
itertools.product(*x)
```